# Помогите исправить код на Java

Tags: java

Пользователь вводит целые числа до тех пор, пока не введёт слово "СТОП" (гарантируется, что других слов не будет). Найдите произведение ненулевых чисел. Если же такое произведение найти не удалось, то выведите на экран "Не найдено".

Если ввести цифры 3,0,2,4 то код работает верно. Если же ввести например 0,0,2,0 то ответ не верен,выводится ответ "2" хотя по идее должно быть "Не найдено".
Но как сделать чтобы работало при вводе цифр 0,0,2,0  не пойму.
Решение хотелось бы делать через цикл for.
Заранее спасибо.
Есть такой код:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean is_0 = false;
        int sum = 1;

        for (String s = sc.nextLine();; s = sc.nextLine()) {
            if ((s.equals("СТОП"))) {
                break;
            }
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (n != 0) {
                sum = sum * n;
                is_0 = true;
            }
        }
        if(!is_0)
            System.out.println("Не найдено");
        else System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Каков результат для ввода 0 0 2 0 ожидается и каков не верный?

Comment: Да всё работает, найти произведение не нулевых чисел 0,0,2,0.
Если ты ввёл только одно число то его на что умножать то надо? на ОДИН ОТВЕТ: 2.
Если нет, то задание надо поменять и как минимум, для ввода требуется две цифры.

Comment: @MeT, вы правы с идей, но автор прав - работает неверно, по заданию он точно не должен выдать ответ 2, а должен - "не найдено", так как произведение найти не удалось. И не обязательно менять задание - см. мой ответ ниже.

Comment: А почему ПРОИЗВЕДЕНИЕ названо sum?

Comment: @Эникейщик, переименовано для порядка в ответе.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, вы были крайне правы:-) Там действительно запихали логику, что при одном числе произведение ему равно. Математически и логически это неверно. "Найдите произведение ненулевых чисел. Если же такое произведение найти не удалось," однозначно должно трактоваться, как "неверно". (Напоминает дзен-загадку про звук хлопка одной рукой. Составитель - дзен-буддист:-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте счетчик и его проверку, если ошибка из-за того, что один множитель есть, и потому произведение неверно считается. Код ниже, но java я вообще не знаю, синтаксис брал по аналогии с вашим. Спасибо @Андрюха, который указал на ряд ошибок. Но первый код ниже не принимается валидатором, так как там логика, что если одно ненулевое число, то произведение ему равно, принимается второй. Странная логика у разработчика, а у @Владимира Клыкова она лучше, чем у меня:-)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean is_0 = false;
        int prod = 0;
        
        int count = 0;

        for (String s = sc.nextLine();; s = sc.nextLine()) {
            if ((s.equals("СТОП"))) {
                break;
            }
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (n != 0) {
                if (count == 0){
                    prod = 1;
                } prod = prod * n;
                count = count + 1;
            }            
        }
        if(prod == 0){
            System.out.println("Не найдено");
        }else if (count == 1){
            System.out.println("Не найдено");
        }else System.out.println(prod);
    }
}
```

Вот код, который валидатор принимает:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean is_0 = false;
        int prod = 0;
        
        int count = 0;
        int one_digit = 0;
        

        for (String s = sc.nextLine();; s = sc.nextLine()) {
            if ((s.equals("СТОП"))) {
                break;
            }
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (n != 0) {
                if (count == 0){
                    prod = 1;
                    one_digit = n;
                } prod = prod * n;
                count = count + 1;
            }            
        }
        if(prod == 0){
            System.out.println("Не найдено");
        }else if (count == 1){
            System.out.println(one_digit);
        }else System.out.println(prod);
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас `sum == 0` никогда не будет истиной.

Comment: @Андрюха, это я автору доверился:-) Он же писал только про 0 2 0 0, вот для его случая я и исправил. Добавил проверку, теперь должно быть.

Comment: а теперь, если первый элемент ноль, то `is_0=true` вне зависимости от остальных чисел :)

Comment: @Андрюха, ага, тоже исправил. В общем, не буду больше править чужие коды, не имея компилятора под рукой и доверяясь словам, что "остальное работает" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, действительно проблема была здесь

```
if (sum == 0) {
                is_0 = true;
            }
```

если изменить  цикл for вот так, то валидатор решение принимает

```
for (String s = sc.nextLine();; s = sc.nextLine()) {
            if ((s.equals("СТОП"))) {
                break;
            }
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (n != 0) {
                sum = sum * n;
                is_0 = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Дмитрий, это как "валидатор решение принимает"? В таком варианте у вас `is_0 = true` сработает при первой же ненулевой цифре и по завершении `for` должно сработать `if(is_0)` - разве нет?

Comment: по ходу валидатор багованный, решение все еще не верно, по есть код то принимается как верный, но если ввести цифры 0,0,2,0 когда по идее результат должен быть "Не найдено", то по итогу имеем вывод "2"

Comment: 1) что за валидатор? 2) Мой код из ответа ниже вы проверили?

Comment: На stepic.org, ваш код вроде правильно работает но  проверку на валидаторе stepic.org не проходит, может уже я что то не понимаю

Comment: дайте название курса (надеюсь, он бесплатный?) и урок, пожалуйста. Запишусь на курс и проверю сам ("ваш код вроде правильно работает" и "проверку на валидаторе stepic.org не проходит" - не стыкуется. Вероятно, у меня просто правильный синтаксис).

Comment: https://stepik.org/course/82867 (бесплатный) , 1.9 Цикл for. Команды break и continue, 11 задание

Comment: У вас не мог работать мой код в таком виде.  Там же две ошибки было в синтаксисе:-) Исправил в коде. И тест 4 валится, посмотрю сейчас.

Comment: Заработало ("You are right, well done!") - добавил рабочий код в ответ. Вам совет - учитесь учиться, а именно: в комментариях под заданием была масса полезной информации - читайте её, примеряйте к своему случаю. Я там и нашёл верный совет от Рената (см. "4 тест, я его вычислил, :)") - странная логика разработчика курса.  Надеюсь, ко мне не явятся теперь смоленские учителя с требованием, чтобы я закончил проходить курс:-)